# Refill a codeigniter form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have some problems to refill a CodeIgniter form.

Currently, I'm doing that :

View :

```
       <div class="line_grid" style="height: 45px; overflow: visible;">
            <div class="g_5">
                <div class="g_3 label"><?php echo form_label('Partenaire commercial : ', 'partenaire'); ?></div>
                <div class="g_9"><?php echo form_dropdown('partenaire', $partenaires,$preselect_partenaire,'onchange = "loadNewCommerciaux(this)" id="partenaire" class="chzn-select" title="" '); ?></div>
                <?php echo form_error('partenaire'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="line_grid" style="height: 45px; overflow: visible;">
            <div class="g_5">
                <div class="g_3 label"><?php echo form_label('Commercial : ', 'commercial'); ?></div>
                <div class="g_3"><?php echo form_dropdown('commercial',$commerciaux,set_value('commercial',$this->form_data->commercial),'id="commercial" class="chzn-select" title="" placeholder="Sélectionner..."'); ?></div>
                <?php echo form_error('commercial'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="g_5">
                <div class="g_3 label"><?php echo form_label('Interlocuteur principal : ', 'principal'); ?></div>
                <div class="g_3"><?php echo form_dropdown('principal', $intervenants,set_value('principal',$this->form_data->principal),'id="principal" class="chzn-select" title="" placeholder="Sélectionner..."'); ?></div>
                <?php echo form_error('principal'); ?>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Javascript :

```
<script>
function loadNewCommerciaux(that){
    urlRequest = window.location.protocol.toString() +"//" +
                                window.location.hostname.toString()  + 
                                window.location.port.toString()  + "/cartel/projets/refillPartenairesCommerciaux/" + that.value
    $.post(
        urlRequest,

        function(data){ 
            alert(result);
            //$("#commercial").load("contenu.html");
        },

        'text' 
     );
}
```

Controller :

```
function refillPartenairesCommerciaux($id_structure){

    $partenaires = array();
    $contacts = $this->db->query('SELECT id, prenom, nom FROM contacts WHERE structure='.$id_structure)->result();
    foreach($contacts as $partenaire){
        $partenaires[$partenaire->id] = $partenaire->prenom . ' ' . $partenaire->nom;
    }

    echo json_encode($partenaires);

}
```

I would like to refill my form_dropdown "commercial" but I have no idea how to do it. 
Currently, the Ajax request allow me to do a new query and the data is returned. How can I refill my form_dropdown with the new data returned by the query without reload the whole page?

Thank you in advance and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Elobarate more about the issue and what you need

Comment: I use the form helper for this. Then in your view you could use `<?php echo set_value("<fieldname>") ?>` and CI will refill the form after incorrectly submitting it. More info: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
In controller :

```
function refillPartenairesCommerciaux($id_structure){

    $html = '';
    $contacts = $this->db->query('SELECT id, prenom, nom FROM contacts WHERE structure='.$id_structure)->result();
    foreach($contacts as $partenaire){
        $html .= '<option value="'.$partenaire->id.'">'.$partenaire->prenom . ' ' . $partenaire->nom.'</option>';
    }

    echo json_encode($html);

}
```

In javascript :

decode response (data) and load to your select tag

```
$("#commercial").html(JSON.parse(data));
```